# Integration of $\int\frac{1}{\cos x(5-4\sin x)}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int\dfrac{1}{\cos x(5-4\sin x)}\, dx$$

I have tried multiple methods like converting this into partial fractions or substitution but no positive!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternative hint:
$$
\frac{5+4\sin x}{\cos x}-\frac{16\cos x}{5-4\sin x}=\frac{25-16\sin^2x-16\cos^2x}{\cos x\cdot (5-4\sin x)}=\frac{9}{\cos x\cdot (5-4\sin x)}
$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** One way is $\sin x=u$ then
$$\int\dfrac{1}{(\cos x)(5-4\sin x)}\,dx=\int\dfrac{\cos x\, dx}{(1-\sin^2x)(5-4\sin x)}=\int\dfrac{du}{(1-u^2)(5-4u)}$$

Comment: In the original question, x multiplies (5-...) and after cos is evaluated ?

Comment: Not so. Notice more!

Comment: Sorry, a few lost, your answer is about cos(x(5-sin(x))) or (cos x)(5-sin(x)) ?

Comment: Surely the second.

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$.

Thus, $dt=\frac{1}{2}(1+t^2)dx$ and
$$\int\frac{1}{\cos{x}(5-4\sin{x})}dx=\int\frac{\frac{2}{1+t^2}}{\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\left(5-\frac{8t}{1+t^2}\right)}dt=$$
$$=\int\frac{2(1+t^2)}{(1-t^2)(5t^2-8t+5)}dt...$$
$$\frac{2(1+t^2)}{(1-t^2)(5t^2-8t+5)}=\frac{8}{9}\frac{5t-4}{5t^2-8t+5}-\frac{1}{t-1}+\frac{1}{9(1+t)}.$$

Comment: @user236182 I don't agree with you. See please better my computations.

Comment: If one is going for a change of variables, there are simpler ones.

Answer (score -1):

Let,
$$Y=\int\dfrac{  1}{cos(x)(5-4sin(x)}
  =\int \dfrac{  1}{\dfrac{1-tan^2(x/2)}{1+tan^2(x/2)}  ×  (5-4\dfrac{2tan(x/2)}{1+tan^2(x/2))})}$$
Now,simplify it and then put  $tan(x/2)=t$

On differentiate bhoth side with d(t)
I.e.  d(tan(x/2))/d(t)=d(t)/d(t)
      sec^2(x/2)/2   ×  d(x)/d(t)=1
      sec^2(x/2)d(x)=2d(t)

Comment: What about $dx$?

Comment: $dt=\frac{1}{2}(1+t^2)\, dx$.